# SharePoint 2010 Require Destination Folder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

Is it possible to make the Destination Folder required? Something besides the default "/" forcing the user to use the Choose Folder.

[image: Destination Folder]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make the Destination Folder required.

If it is a normal page like newform.aspx, we could use js code to do this. However,the upload.aspx page is an application page. We cannot make any customzations in application page.

Comment: Thank you for the info.